# Running two background tasks in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, concurrency, xamarin.forms, task

I would like to run two background threads on my xamarin form mobile app.

The problem is that I would like those tasks to be invoked at different frequencies.

To call one, I did this:

```
 protected  override void OnStart()
    {
        // Handle when your app starts
        // On start runs when your application launches from a closed state, 
        if (!stopWatch.IsRunning)
        {
            stopWatch.Start();
        }

        Device.StartTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1), () =>
       {
           if (stopWatch.IsRunning && stopWatch.Elapsed.Seconds == 20) //first task
           {
               MyMethod(this).ContinueWith((Task t) =>
                {
                    stopWatch.Restart();
                       return true;
                });
           }


         //second method?



           //  Always return true as to keep our device timer running, false if we want to cancel the timer.
           return true;
        });
    }
```

That piece of code runs well. The problem is that I would like to call a second task but with a different frequency. Where should I put it?

Comment: Right below the first one? Just copy and paste starting from `Device.StartTimer` and create a `stopWatch2` variable.

Comment: @hvaughan3 , it does not work. The first task(method) is always called as it is called at a lower frequency than the second method which is called every 50 seconds. The second method is never called.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use one Timer using an interval that works for both of them and use a counter to see which to fire.

For instance if you have 1 task to run at 20 seconds and another one at thirty seconds.  Have your interval set for 10 seconds.  Use a class level variable to hold the count and reset it after the second task.

```
        intervalCount++;
        if(intervalCount == 2)
        {
            // Do function 1
        }
        else if(intervalCount == 3)
        {
            // Do function 2 and reset our counter
            intervalCount == 0;
        }
```

Comment: That does not work either. Function 2 is never called.